# Do mods prevent you from achieving achievements?

Tags: civilization-5, achievements

If you play w/ a mod, will it prevent you from getting an achievement in the game? I'm a huge fan of the Luxury display mod, and would hate to have to play w/out it... but I do want to try and get the achievements...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Yes.** Any game achievements you earn will **not** be registered by steam while **any** mod is active.

It does not matter whether or not the mod effects the particular achievement in any way.

Comment: Does this include if a mod was played at some other point in the game? For example, could I use the luxury mod until right before I win with <person I haven't beaten the game with> and then save, reload w/out the mod and win to get the achievement, or would I have to play the entire game w/out any mods?

Comment: @aslum: I have not tried re-loading a game with different mod's enabled but I would think(hope) that a game is 'invalidated' once any mod is used, otherwise nearly all achievements would be easily obtained with a corresponding mod.

Comment: I just completed a game with several mods enabled (all of which had "Affects Save Games" set to No) and didn't get credit for achievements, but was able to go back to my last autosave with no mods and get credit.

Comment: I wish i'd known this before embarking on a marathon session to get the Bollywood medal. Took ages, and no reward. Boo

Comment: Mods that aren't enabled in-game, such as EUI, do not affect achievements.