# What are the complete requirements of the Bollywood Achievement?

Tags: steam, civilization-5

I'm very curious is there some kind of requirement(s) I'm unaware of for the Bollywood Achievement:

> **Bollywood**
>
> As Gandhi, win a cultural victory with 3 or fewer cities in your empire.

I'm only asking this question because I have actually accomplished this achievement several times but Steam has never awarded me for the achievement.I went ahead and started a new game as Gandhi and accomplished the listed requirements (3 or fewer cities in my empire and win by culture victory) again just as is stated in the achievement and again no achievement received. Also, never had more than 3 cities the entire game.

So I'm just wondering what gives?

Is there some kind of unlisted requirements for the achievement? The achievement states as follows:

Does it require a specific difficulty? Does it require that no game modifications are used? Does it require that you never go to war with any other civilization or city-state?

I'm just at a loss because I just barely completed this achievement exactly as it is stated for like the 19th time and I still have not received the achievement.

Comment: Does the previous question not answer your question?

Comment: @DavidMFox By previous question Frank meant the question that is linked with your question on the right hand side of the page under the category "Linked". It is a question that was asked previously that the site detected was extremely similar to your own. The site does this so it is easier to identify duplicate questions. Also you might want to read up on this: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice

Comment: @closevoters: This isn't actually a duplicate. The user isn't looking for tips to complete the achievement, they're wondering if there are any additional requirements or gotchas for it to activate (i.e. you need to be on a certain difficulty, you can't have mods on)

Answer (score 3):

> Does it require that no game modifications are used?

[Yes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10099/do-mods-prevent-you-from-achieving-achievements). Mods will disable all achievements from activating, including the **Bollywood** achievement.